# Firebase Cloud functions: Typescript does not compile to JavaScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Cloud function on my computer works with Javascript, but when I try it using TypeScript it does not compile to Javascript. It does not event create lib/index.js

When I run firebase deploy, it shows the error that

```
Error: There was an error reading functions/package.json:
```

firebase deploy --debug shows the following log:

```
APPLEs-MacBook-Air:functions abbasi$ firebase deploy --debug
[2020-01-08T08:39:06.383Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-01-08T08:39:06.390Z] Command:       /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/firebase deploy --debug
[2020-01-08T08:39:06.390Z] CLI Version:   7.11.0
[2020-01-08T08:39:06.390Z] Platform:      darwin
[2020-01-08T08:39:06.391Z] Node Version:  v12.14.1
[2020-01-08T08:39:06.392Z] Time:          Wed Jan 08 2020 13:39:06 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)
[2020-01-08T08:39:06.393Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[2020-01-08T08:39:06.393Z] 
[2020-01-08T08:39:06.422Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[2020-01-08T08:39:06.423Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
[2020-01-08T08:39:06.426Z] [iam] checking project safepay-test for permissions ["cloudfunctions.functions.create","cloudfunctions.functions.delete","cloudfunctions.functions.get","cloudfunctions.functions.list","cloudfunctions.functions.update","cloudfunctions.operations.get","firebase.projects.get"]
[2020-01-08T08:39:06.429Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/safepay-test:testIamPermissions  
 permissions=[cloudfunctions.functions.create, cloudfunctions.functions.delete, cloudfunctions.functions.get, cloudfunctions.functions.list, cloudfunctions.functions.update, cloudfunctions.operations.get, firebase.projects.get]
[2020-01-08T08:39:08.205Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 content-type=application/json; charset=UTF-8, vary=X-Origin, Referer, Origin,Accept-Encoding, date=Wed, 08 Jan 2020 08:39:08 GMT, server=ESF, cache-control=private, x-xss-protection=0, x-frame-options=SAMEORIGIN, x-content-type-options=nosniff, server-timing=gfet4t7; dur=1374, alt-svc=quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000, accept-ranges=none, transfer-encoding=chunked

=== Deploying to 'safepay-test'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build
✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
[2020-01-08T08:39:13.911Z] > [functions] package.json contents: {
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "8"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6"
  },
  "private": true
}

Error: There was an error reading functions/package.json:

 functions/lib/index.js does not exist, can't deploy Cloud Functions

Having trouble? Try firebase [command] --help
```

I have just tried it on another colleague's Macbook, it works on his system perfectly, but not on my system.

Kindly help me with this.

Comment: What error do you see when you use `tsc` by hand? Put `npx tsc index.js`.

Comment: what should I type in terminal?

Comment: npx tsc lib/index.ts

Comment: It has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to know that Typescript was not installed.

Resolved with

```
sudo npm install -g typescript
```

Now it is working ifne

Comment: **You shouldn't have to install typescript globally like this.**  It just needs to be installed in your project, defined in package.json, which it was.  Maybe you never ran `npm install` in your project to actually install it.

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same problem:
Typescript just wouldn't compile. Logging a lot of errors, mostly like this one here: **"error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'AbortController'"**

The solution:

Just added the following line inside the "compilerOptions" property in the tsconfig.json file:

**"typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]**

Like that:

**/functions/tsconfig.json**

```
{ 
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "noImplicitReturns": true,
      "noUnusedLocals": true,
      "outDir": "lib", 
      "sourceMap": true,
      "strict": true,
      "target": "es2017",
      "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]  // <-- here
    },  
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "include": ["src"]
  }
}
```

After that it compiled just fine!

Comment: Your solution worked for me. I think it happens when the parent folder is also a TypeScript project, with it's own tsconfig.json etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you clone a repo that contains a node project, including a Cloud Functions project, **the first thing you should do** is change to the directory where package.json is defined, and run `npm install`.  This will rebuild the contents of node_modules which was not checked into source control.  If you don't run `npm install`, then the project will not actually know anything about any of the modules defined in package.json.

Answer (score 0):

**This solved it for me**

after trying many solutions to get the build working, it worked when I uncommented the code in `index.ts`

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

// // Start writing Firebase Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript
//
// export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
//   functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
//   response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
// });
```

It was caused because the imported `functions` variable was declared but not used