# Firebase CLI deploy Error: There was an error reading functions/package.json

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I recently getting this error when try to deploy the firebase cloud functions using the command `firebase deploy --only functions`. My package.json file is shown below

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "10"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.12.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.2",
    "stripe": "^8.50.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.6",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.0",
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Using npm package `firebase-tools` of version `8.4.1`.

Also getting error in `firebase emulators`[image: error in terminal while serve it locally]

Comment: There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59694126/firebase-cloud-functions-typescript-does-not-compile-to-javascript) with the similar case with yours. Could you take a look and let me know if that helps?

Answer (score 6):

1. Enter into functions directory
2. enter the following command `npm run build`
3. and then deploy / launch your emulators

Answer (score 2):

To me what happened was that I added a `test` folder out side of src folder. Because I use typescript the typesctipt compiler lost it and changed the output directory.

So if that's the case, move the other folders inside `src`.